# Template not rendering with Iron: Router

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to setup a layoutTemplate in Iron: Router. I've read the documentation i've implemented it in my own project (as to reduce repeating code). Something is wrong though. The inner template is rendering but not the layout.

Layout File located at 'client/templates/defaultlayout.html'

```
<template name="defaultlayout">
  <head>
    <title>Grocery Getter</title>
  </head>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      {{> yield "headerButtons"}}
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      {{> loginButtons}}
      {{> yield "headertextinput"}}
    </header>
    <body>
      {{> yield}}
    </body>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is the template that I want to populate the '{{> yield}}' section located at 'client/templates/login.html':

```
<template name="login">
  <h4>Please login or create an account.</h4>
</template>
```

And here is my Iron: Router stuff located at 'client/routes.js':

```js
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'defaultlayout'
});
Router.route('/',function()
{
  if(!Meteor.user())
    {
      this.redirect('/login');
    }
  else
    {
      this.redirect('/householdsignup');
    }
});

Router.route('/login',function()
{
  if(!Meteor.user())
    {
      this.render('login', function(){
        data: 'Grocery Getter'
      });
    }
    else
    {
      this.redirect('/householdsignup');
    }
});
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout doesn't look valid to me. To the best of my knowledge templates can't have heads. Don't you get an error from meteor?

Try this instead:

main.html:

```
<head>
  <title>Grocery Getter</title>
</head>
```

defaultlayout.html:

```
<template name="defaultlayout">
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      {{> yield "headerButtons"}}
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      {{> loginButtons}}
      {{> yield "headertextinput"}}
    </header>
    {{> yield}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Also, you may want to move the routes.js into the shared client/server space, e.g., in the project root.

Comment: Thanks! That worked out perfectly! I'm learning how to write in this platform little by little.